# Preventing table header resizing when setting it to the top of a window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with element resizing on a webpage. I've dynamically created a table from some json-data. I've got a function that fixes a tables header into the top of the page when the window scrolls past through it:

```
var header = $("#dataheader").offset();

$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() > header.top){
    $("#dataheader").css('top','0').css('background-color',white)
} else {
    $('#dataheader').css('position', 'static');
}
});
```

Now, the CSS width for the header (and it's cells) are set to "auto". This also means that when the function appends the header to the top of the window, it resizes the header so that its cells are no longer aligned with the column. Instead, they become shorter.

Is there a way for me to prevent this from happening, or to set the element widths by getting them from the columns?

Answer (score 0):

Add the same width before and after static

```
var header = $("#dataheader").offset();

$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() > header.top){
    $("#dataheader").css('position', 'static').css('top','0').css('width',header.width).css('left',header.left).css('background-color','white');
} else {
    $('#dataheader').css('position', 'relative').css('top','').css('width','100%').css('left','').css('background-color','');
}
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem, as it only extends the white background color to be the width of the header element. It does not keep the cells of the header the same size, as they still shrink.